# Desktop doesn't load due to intel_agp errors

Tags: 10.10, installation, drivers, intel-graphics

Today I have installed the ubuntu system on my notebook.
After rebooting, I cannot enter the desktop, the log program
stopped in terminal, it says "unknown signal" from my intel
graphic card,

> i915: gave up waiting for init of module intel_agp.
>   i915: Unknown symbol intel_agp_enabled (err-16)
>   i915: gave up waiting for init of module intel_agp.
>   i915: Unknown symbol intel_max_stolen (err-16)

and I think something bad happened to my driver,
finally i can do nothing but enter commands in
a text-mode terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for that error message on the internet, you find [the following entry on the ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1601023).  It seems this is a reported bug ([#665097](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/665097)) and there exists a work-around by blacklisting the intel_ips module, the procedure for which is also provided there in post #7.  I hope this can also solve your problems.

For blacklisting, boot into recovery mode as root, then:

1. edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
2. add the line `blacklist intel_ips`
3. reboot